# Digging into the Kinect for Windows SDK... just opened up the source files, missing references already?

Tags: kinect

I downloaded the Kinect for Windows SDK as well as Visual Studio Express 2012. I installed some of the WPF applications from the SDK browser and they worked wonderfully with the sensor.

Problem is, I open up the .sln to explore how these applications are built and I start getting broken references immediately without having changed anything. I can hardly open any of the XAML files without getting errors like these (all from the project InteractionGallery-WPF):

Content\PannableContentScreen\WorldMap.xaml, line 3, column 9: "Uri is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project."

Content\ArticleScreen\Article1.xaml, line 5: "The property "ImageUris" does not have an accessible setter."

Content\ArticleScreen\Article1.xaml, line 7: "The property "Paragraphs" can only be set once."

Content\MainWindow.xaml, line 20: "Type Microsoft.Expression.WpfPlatform.InstanceBuilders.WindowInstance does not support event: Closed"

So, a pretty frustrating first couple of hours with it so far. I did a number of searches already for the text of these errors and could not find anyone else who was having these issues. I should mention that I do not come from a Microsoft background, so my troubleshooting skills are very low in this area - but all the same, I was kind of hoping that the stuff provided by Microsoft would work out of the box so I could break it myself without it coming that way!

Note that it still builds without error, and the application runs fine when debugging. But I'd sure like to be able to use the Design view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to add references in Visual Studio?. Basically you will need to add reference to Kinect library manually by your self. Search for 'how to' s you will find opening few tabs..

Comment: The .sln file came with all the references added... I see the three Kinect libraries (Kinect, Kinect.Toolkit and Kinect.Toolkit.Controls) listed under my project's references. The errors seem to be in relation to the XAML schema, but I have the XAML reference added as well. Seems strange to me that it's saying "Uri is not supported" when that's a pretty important component of WPF!

Answer (score 0):

What I did is just a simple step which hope will work for you as well. Click on your article and then in the properties area you will see build action which page automatically. Change that to resource and you won't longer see that error again.

Good luck